# Is lightning message channel package-able

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, managed-package, package, lightning-message-service

I have used the lightning message channel in LWC and I want to package the same. But lightning message channel is not available in the list. Also, [the component available in the managed pacakge](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm) doesnot include anything about the lightning message channel nor it is mentioned in the [lightning message channel limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/message_channel_considerations.htm) doc.

So, is it packageable or not? Or will it be directly added through the dependency?

Answer (score 4):

LightningMessageChannel Represents the metadata associated with a Lightning Message Channel. A Lightning Message Channel represents a secure channel to communicate across UI technologies (Lightning Web Components, Aura Components, and Visualforce).

As per Metadata Coverage report, LightningMessageChannel component are packagable:
[image]

Refer [Metadata Coverage](https://mdcoverage.secure.force.com/docs/metadata-coverage/52)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can add the lightning message channel to a managed package because I do it. "Lightning Message Channel" in list.
Here is it[image]